# How to retrieve the length and width of the drawn shape in google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Using the google maps api, how do i get the dimensions of the drawn shape?

I want to get the dimensions and add some sort of labels on top of the drawn shape.

[Here's an img showing what i'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnxQY.png)

The `event` argument on `overlay` event doesn't show the length and width of the drawn shape. Hope somebody can help me with a solution for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getBounds()` method of your Polygon to get the coordinates, and then use the latlng to compute for the distance.

This SO question has an Javascript implementation of how to compute the distance :
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html